# GORM Find(&room) operation populating struct with null data instead of actual data

Tags: go, go-gorm, go-fiber

I am using GORM to connect to my DB. I am using GoFiber for the application. I have two endpoints, a GET to List all rooms and a POST to create a ROOM. I am using Gorm MySQL driver and connecting to a DB hosted at PlanetScale.

My Model:-

```
type Room struct {
    Model
    RoomType string `json:"room_type" validate:"required"`
}
```

My Get Endpoint Code:-

```
func GetAllRooms(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
    var rooms []entities.Room

    res := database.Database.Find(&rooms)
    
    if res.RowsAffected != 0 {
        return c.JSON(fiber.Map{"rooms": rooms})
    } else {
        return c.JSON(fiber.Map{"rooms": nil})
    }
}
```

My Database Code:-(hosted at planetscale)

```
var Database *gorm.DB

func ConnectDb() {
    dsn := "sample_dsn/mydatabase?tls=true&interpolateParams=true"
    db, err := gorm.Open(mysql.Open(dsn))
    if err != nil {
        panic("Failed to connect to DB")
    }
    // Setup Migrations Here
    db.AutoMigrate(&entities.Booking{})
    db.AutoMigrate(&entities.Inventory{})
    db.AutoMigrate(&entities.Room{})
    db.AutoMigrate(&entities.User{})
    Database = db
}
```

Output In Console:-

```
{{1 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC {0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC false}} }
{{2 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC {0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC false}} }
{{3 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC {0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC false}} }
{{4 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC {0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC false}} }
```

Data in DB:-

```
id       created_at              updated_at          deleted_at      **room_type**
1   2024-01-18 19:27:36.680   2024-01-18 19:27:36.680                 DOUBLE_ROOM
2   2024-01-18 19:27:41.206   2024-01-18 19:27:41.206                 DOUBLE_ROOM
3   2024-01-18 19:27:49.403   2024-01-18 19:27:49.403                 KING_SIZE_AC
4   2024-01-19 11:06:11.789   2024-01-19 11:06:11.789                 DOUBLE_BED
```

API Output:-

```
{
  "rooms": [
    {
      "ID": 1,
      "CreatedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
      "UpdatedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
      "DeletedAt": null,
      "room_type": ""
    },
    {
      "ID": 2,
      "CreatedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
      "UpdatedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
      "DeletedAt": null,
      "room_type": ""
    },
    {
      "ID": 3,
      "CreatedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
      "UpdatedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
      "DeletedAt": null,
      "room_type": ""
    },
    {
      "ID": 4,
      "CreatedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
      "UpdatedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
      "DeletedAt": null,
      "room_type": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

**Update:- 01/20/2024** 
This exact code works when I switch to Postgres Database. So I am switching to Postgres and closing this ticket.

Comment: Please post the code and error as a text, and not an image.

Comment: Sorry, replaced images with text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a quick test with the below code:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2"
    "gorm.io/driver/postgres"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
    "log"
)

var (
    dsn = "host=localhost user=postgres password=secret dbname=mySampleDb port=5432 sslmode=disable"
)

type Room struct {
    gorm.Model
    RoomType string `json:"room_type" validate:"required"`
}

var DB *gorm.DB

func main() {
    initDb()
    app := fiber.New()

    app.Get("/", getAllRoomsForFiber)

    app.Listen(":3000")
}
func getAllRoomsForFiber(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
    var rooms []Room
    res := DB.Find(&rooms)
    if res.RowsAffected != 0 {
        return c.JSON(fiber.Map{"rooms": rooms})
    } else {
        return c.JSON(fiber.Map{"rooms": nil})
    }
}

func seedDb() {
    DB.Create(&Room{RoomType: "single"})
    DB.Create(&Room{RoomType: "Deluxe bed"})
    DB.Create(&Room{RoomType: "Twin bed"})
    DB.Create(&Room{RoomType: "King Size bed"})
}
func initDb() {
    db, err := gorm.Open(postgres.Open(dsn))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("couldn't connect to db")
    }
    DB = db
    db.AutoMigrate(&Room{})
    seedDb()
}
```

And this is what I get:

```
{
  "rooms":[
    {
      "ID":1,
      "CreatedAt":"2024-01-19T15:54:10.19868+03:00",
      "UpdatedAt":"2024-01-19T15:54:10.19868+03:00",
      "DeletedAt":null,
      "room_type":"single"
    },
    {
      "ID":2,
      "CreatedAt":"2024-01-19T15:54:10.199816+03:00",
      "UpdatedAt":"2024-01-19T15:54:10.199816+03:00",
      "DeletedAt":null,
      "room_type":"King Size Bed"
    },
    {
      "ID":3,
      "CreatedAt":"2024-01-19T15:55:07.110176+03:00",
      "UpdatedAt":"2024-01-19T15:55:07.110176+03:00",
      "DeletedAt":null,
      "room_type":"Twin Bed"
    },
    {
      "ID":4,
      "CreatedAt":"2024-01-19T15:55:07.115137+03:00",
      "UpdatedAt":"2024-01-19T15:55:07.115137+03:00",
      "DeletedAt":null,
      "room_type":"Deluxe bed"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I'm using planet scale for the DB, could it be an isolated case in this instance only ?

Comment: Updated my DB Code in the ticket description.

Comment: @Sarnava, I don't know, I don't use mysql nor planet scale. You could simply check if it is the case by temporarily setting your db to, say postgreSQL. You don't even have to install it, you can use docker image.

Comment: Works when I switch to Postgres.